# JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs not working on OS X

Tags: c++, macos, jvm, java-native-interface

I'm trying to fetch the JVM instances using JNI in an injected dylib. I'm new to this on mac, and have looked up examples and usages of JNI in OS X, from what i can see it's fairly similar (if not the same).

I have a method to retrieve the created JavaVM instances from the JVM i'm injecting into, this is where it gets stuck...

```
bool Payload::GetJNIInstances() {
    jsize nVMs;
    int res = JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs(NULL, 0, &nVMs); // this line crashes the JVM

    // Doesn't even get to the null/invalid check.
    if (res != JNI_OK || nVMs == 0) {
        printf("Failed to get JVM instance (A)");
        return false;
    }
```

I noticed the method is deprecated on OS X and i wonder if that has something to do with it. I checked out the JNI header file for any clues as to how else i could do this on OS X, but most methods are deprecated, except 2 (JNI_OnLoad and JNI_OnUnload) which aren't of any use to me for this task.

Reason i'm confused is that this same method works fine on Windows (calling JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs) without fail, and the Java versions i installed are the same (jre130_131).

Is there something i'm missing that's required when doing this in OS X or is this the completely wrong method of fetching the JVM's on OS X?

EDIT: I tested using JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs with the following args but I get the same crash:
JavaVM *vm[1], jint 1, jint &nVMs

This is the crash report (should be all the information from the report you'd need):

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000010f14c704, pid=776, tid=0x0000000000004f03
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_144-b01) (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.144-b01 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x000000010f14c704
```

Any ideas?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It works for me. How do you compile and run this code?

Comment: In case the problem is caused by NULL, try `JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs(&vm, 1, &nVMs);` where vm is declared as `JavaVM *vm;`

Comment: @apangin I'm using CLion to compile it. Does it not crash the Java process when run for you? It could be something with my current version.

I'll also try the non-null version... I'll come back to you when i've tried it. Thanks